# Unnecessary warnings in the code

Tags: iphone

I am not able to find out why am I getting unnecessary warnings like:
"Method 'someMethod' not found"? Though at run time it is executing this method and I am getting the desired results. FYI... The called method resides in separate class which i have already imported in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one of two reasons:

1) You haven't casted the object that you're calling that method on correctly.

```
[(UITableView*)myTableView setDelegate:self];
```

2) The method that you're calling may not be in your custom Class' (public) @interface

```
@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject {

}

- (void)doSomethingReallyImportant;

@end
```

Comment: You are right. That was the mistake. Now, I have added this method to the protocol to which my class was bind to. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do something to an object, did you cast your object to the object's class?

If you are trying to access a method in your implementation of a class, do you have that method declared in your .h?

Answer (score 0):

Then you have probably not put that method in the class' `@interface`. You should if it is a public method.

Being able to compile without warnings is a good thing.

Comment: Or if it isn't supposed to be API, add the declaration to a class continuation.